# xorg.conf for 2 X servers on 1 video card

Tags: x11

It should be possible to run 2 X servers from 1 video card, right? I can get my system to run 2 X servers on **2** video cards (Nvidia 960 and the motherboard video), but I cannot get 2 X servers running on just the Nvidia card using its Display Port and HDMI port.

Here is my xorg.conf file for 2 X servers on 1 video card (note I removed all the InputDevice sections for brevity here):

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option         "DefaultServerLayout" "seat0"
    Option         "AllowMouseOpenFail"  "true"
    Option         "AutoAddDevices"      "false"
    Option         "AutoEnableDevices"   "false"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "seat0"
    Screen         "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Touchscreen0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Seat"  "seat0"
    Option         "SingleCard" "on"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "seat1"
    Screen         "Screen1" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard1" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Touchscreen1" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Seat"  "seat1"
    Option         "SingleCard" "on"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL E196FP"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL E170S"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Videocard0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Videocard1"
    Driver         "vesa"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Option         "ProbeAllGpus"          "false"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Videocard0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth   24
    Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP"
    Option         "AddARGBVisuals" "True"
    Option         "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
    Option         "DynamicTwinView" "False"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1280x1024 +0+0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Videocard1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth   24
    Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP"
    Option         "AddARGBVisuals" "True"
    Option         "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
    Option         "DynamicTwinView" "False"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-2: 1024x768 +0+0"
EndSection
```

I start each X server with the following commands:

```
startx -- :0 -layout seat0
```

and

```
startx -- :1 -layout seat1 -sharevts
```

What do I need to change to get the Nvidia card to be the source of both X servers?

Comment: You can use ``Videocard0`` in both screens, but you can't run 2 servers on one card concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run two servers on one card: Both servers would have to "own" the same hardware register set, and that doesn't work.

But you can configure one X server to use two *screens*. The displaynames will look like `:0.0` and `:0.1` (instead of `:0` and `:1` for two different servers). The hardware part that does video readout for a screen is also called "head", so this configuration is enabled by the option `ZaphodHeads` in most X drivers, e.g. `intel` and `nouveau` (after Zaphod Beeblebrox). See e.g. [here](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/MultiMonitorDesktop/) for `nouveau`.

The closed-source source `nvidia` driver doesn't have this option IIRC, because they use their own platform-independent *TwinView* structure.

I can only give the configuration for the `intel` driver, as I don't have an Nvidia card, so better follow the documentation for `nouveau` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's why I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Nobody came out and said that though :) Can I have independent cursors with different screens?

Comment: I don't think you can have independent cursors, because it's still one X server, and AFAIK there's no infrastructore for having several core keyboards/pointers. I may be wrong, though, I never tried having different seats on the two screens.

Comment: I did run the test with 2 screens on 1 display and there was only 1 cursor. Using 2 touchscreens would "steal" the cursor to each monitor.

Comment: Yes, that's the normal setup (I run the same here). Also the cursor will move from one screen to the other when you cross the screen border, depending on the layout. But I'm still not 100% that you can't configure something else (unless you tried configuring it, and it didn't work).